# Using dynamic variable in Django Model.objects.filter()

Tags: python, django

I am facing issues with using dynamic variable after submitting form the in Model.objects.filter(). Added my source code below-

```
user_check = UserForm(request.POST)

if user_check.is_valid():
  user_id = user_check['user_id'] #Submitted '9a26b3e5-1892-439b-b392-1779a043ca1a'

  get_user = User.objects.filter(id=user_id)
  num_of_user = get_user.count()
```

If I use direct assignment i.e.

```
  user_id = '9a26b3e5-1892-439b-b392-1779a043ca1a'
  get_user = User.objects.filter(id=user_id)
  num_of_user = get_user.count()
```

then I get 1 for num_of_user but id submitted through form submission always result 0.

Also, after submitting the form then I was able to view the submitted user id back to my frontend template.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get user_id from form's [cleaned_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data):

```
user_id = user_check.cleaned_data.get('user_id')
```

instead of

```
user_id = user_check['user_id']
```

In first case you will get value of user_id field (what you need). But second method returns the field itself which looks like this:

```
<input type='text' name='user_id'>
```